# Can RocksDB settings be changed with the java library while the database is open?

Tags: rocksdb, rocksdb-java

Using the java library, can any configuration changes take effect without requiring a reopen of the database? For example the `level0SlowdownWritesTrigger`.

More context: I'm trying to flip between a bulk-load mode and regular mode. e.g. Disable autocompaction when the app starts up, load the data, then enable autocompaction. In testing this has given me a 75% reduction in initial load time.
The problem is that changes to the `Options` don't take effect, at least in the way I'm making them.  I don't want to have to reopen the database, because that complicates existing data flow handling.

Sample code I've tried. In this example, I'm changing the auto compaction settings in the options.

```kotlin
import org.rocksdb.ColumnFamilyOptions
import org.rocksdb.DBOptions
import org.rocksdb.Options
import org.rocksdb.RocksDB

class ExampleRocksDbStore(
    private val dataDirectory: String,
    private val configureOptions: (options: Options) -> Unit = {},
) {

    val db: RocksDB
    val options: Options

    init {
        RocksDB.loadLibrary()

        ColumnFamilyOptions().use { cfOpts ->
            val dbOptions = DBOptions()

            options = Options(dbOptions, cfOpts).apply {
                setCreateIfMissing(true)
                setCreateMissingColumnFamilies(true)
            }
            configureOptions(options)

            db = RocksDB.open(options, dataDirectory)
        }
    }

    fun enableAutoCompaction() {
        options.setDisableAutoCompactions(false)
    }

    fun disableAutoCompaction() {
        options.setDisableAutoCompactions(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically changeable options are a thing, the [Basic Operations wiki](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Basic-Operations) mentions them:

> Some options can be changed dynamically while DB is running. For example: ...

The only record I can find of which options these are is in `options.h` [here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/include/rocksdb/options.h), there are multiple options tagged with *"// Dynamically changeable through SetOptions() API"*, and `disable_automatic_compactions` [is one of them](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/include/rocksdb/options.h#L276).

So I think you just need to change your `Options` object, then call `setOptions()` on your RocksDB instance, unless you're already doing that and it's not working?

Comment: Thanks @MyStackRunnethOver - to enable autocompactions I think the `db.enableAutoCompaction(List<ColumnFamilyHandle>)` method works.

Calling `setOptions` on the open db looks trickier as I understand it, because it takes the Mutable variation of the options, which doesn't look compatible with the original classes used to open the db.